# C#: Unable to retrieve data from a record set

Tags: c#, database, dataset

The exception that im getting is "There is no row at position 0":

I put the messagebox stub in there to verify that im actually getting a result from the database. Tried different queries and it appears to be working fine. However when I try to retrieve that information from the result set, i keep getting that error. What am i doing wrong? Here is the current code i have loaded, it returns 1 result. I'm trying to take that one result and return it to the program as a double. But regardless of what I'm doing with it, the error im still getting is "no row at position 0". Ive tried position 1 and 2, and the same result.

the query is: "select distinct sweetTarget from productInfo where flavor = 'Classic Coke'"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace DatasetTest1
    {
        class dataLayer
        {

            static string connectionString = "Data Source=HALEY;Initial Catalog=cokeDatabaseSQL;Integrated Security=True";
            static SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            static string sql = "select distinct sweetTarget from productInfo where flavor = 'Classic Coke'";
            static SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            static cokeDatabaseSQLDataSet dataTable = new cokeDatabaseSQLDataSet();

            public static double getTargetBrix()
            {
                double value = 0.00;
                try
                {

                    conn.Open();
                    int affectedRows = da.Fill(dataTable);

                    if (affectedRows > 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Rows Returned: " + affectedRows);
                        value = dataTable.productInfo[0].sweetTarget;
                    }
                    else
                        MessageBox.Show("Empty Set");

                }
                catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }



                return value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your DataSet does not contain a definition for the query you are trying to execute, and the data ends up on a different table. That is, `select distinct ... from productInfo` does not populate the `productInfo` data table inside the `cokeDatabaseSQLDataSet`. You’d need to write something like this to extract the value:

```
value = (double) dataTable.Tables[dataTable.Tables.Count - 1].Rows[0][0];
```

Now, if instead of declaring dataTable as cokeDatabaseSQLDataSet you do this:

```
static DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
```

Then you’ll be able to get the value you’re after with this line:

```
value = (double) dataTable.Rows[0][0];
```

Comment: cokeDatabaseSQLDataSet was created by the IDE when I added the data source so the schema is identical to the database itself. How would it not contain a definition for the query?

Comment: As per the MSDN documentation, "When using subsequent Fill calls to refresh the contents of the DataSet, two conditions must be met: (1) The SQL statement should match the one initially used to populate the DataSet. (2) The Key column information must be present." 

My guess is that because the dynamic query used on the data adapter doesn't match the one on the generated DataSet, then a new table is created. If you examine the file cokeDatabaseSQLDataSet.Designer.css, you'll find the generated queries on the InitCommandCollection() method.

Answer (score 1):

`da.Fill(dataTable)` is used for adding rows to the DataSet. So considering that dataTable is a DataSet, try this:

```
value = dataTable.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]
```

OR

```
value = dataTable.Tables[0].Rows[0][ColumnName]
```

Comment: How many rows are you getting in affected rows? Try to debug and see what values do you have in dataTable object. Where and how have you defined dataTable ?

Comment: for this query, i am getting 1 affected row. When i change the query to select *, i get 87 affected rows. I updated my post to show the code for the entire static class.

Comment: Try this: value = dataTable.productInfo.Rows[0].sweetTarget;

Comment: 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'sweetTarget' and no extension method 'sweetTarget' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: dataTable.productInfo.Rows[0][0] or dataTable.productInfo.Rows[0].Columns[0]

Comment: the first one is still saying no row at position 0, the second one is the same error as the previous comment

Comment: hmm... will have to debug it. Use Data Visualizer in Visual Studio to see what values do you have in the DataSet.

Answer (score 0):

hic ! wrong code

You must read table from Dataset.

Example:

```
foreach (DataRow dRow in affectedRows.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    var retval   = dRow["Keyword"].ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(retval );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the Table Count and Row Count

```
dataTable.Tables.Count

dataTable.Tables[0].Rows.Count
```